# On the occasion of someone's coming back / arrival

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Which one of the sentences below sound more natural to you:

> - He organized a big party **on the occasion of his son’s *coming back***.
> - He organized a big party o**n the occasion of his son’s *arrival***.

Answer (score 1):

I would use *coming back* if someone had been absent but is now returning. For example, if the son had been at university in another country, but was now returning home.

You could use *arrival* in the same sense, but to me *arrival* connotes that the son had not previously been at the place. Maybe the family had moved to a different country and the son had remained to study at a university, but now is the son is moving to the same country as the family and they are celebrating his arrival.

---

On which is more natural, it would sound more natural to use *for* here instead of *on*, as follows:

> He organised a big party **for** his son's coming back.
>   He organised a big party **for** his son's arrival.

If you say *on*, it sounds like the party is organised for the day the son comes back/arrives, but not necessarily that the party was being thrown because of the son coming back/arriving. Using *for*, it shows that the party is for the son coming back/arriving, and it is implied that the party is on the same day (or thereabouts).

Comment: Thank you @LMS, but actually I need to know how / when to use the structure "on the occasion of..."; this is exactly what we say in our language, but if you as a native say that it seems to be unnatural to be heard, then it would be another story and I have find another structure to convey my precise meaning. Do you confirm that it makes my sentence sound slightly wired? :)

Comment: You could also say *for the occasion of his son's coming back* (or *arrival*), but this sounds quite formal and so may or may not be what you want. The for/on difference in my answer still applies.

Comment: Great; many thanks again @LMS. Just please let me know if in American speaking this formally in the manner that you want to be more polite sounds to be a bit show-off or even unnatural or depending on your character background can be acceptable in cultural areas or among educated people or even among ordinary people? I'm asking this question because were I live people always try to be polite, specially when they are not familiar with a company and they are considered a newcomer there.

Comment: I couldn't give definites about American English (my native tongue is British English), but *for the occasion of* would not sound unusual in a professional environment (such as the workplace) or in ordinary speech, although I would expect the sentences in my answer to be more commonly heard and said.

Comment: So you would accept "for" the occasion of ...instead of "on" the occasion of ... in professional environments. That looks enough. Thanks again @LMS